# Creating folder structure with 27x26 i.e of all alphabet with 26 deep level

Tags: node.js, path, fs

I want to create folder structure 27X26 i.e.

```
A/A/B..Z
B/A/B..Z
C/A/B..Z
.
.
Z/A/B..Z
```

I'm trying following code but it is not working.

```
var fs=require('fs'),
    path=require('path');

var arr=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
var itr=0;

function createAtZ(pth){
    if(pth){
        if(itr<676){
            for(let i=0;i<26;i++){
                dir = path.join(__dirname,pth+'/'+arr[i]);
                if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
                    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
                }
            }
            for(let i=0;i<26;i++){
                createAtZ(pth+'/'+arr[i])
            }
        }
    }
    itr++;
}
for(var i=0;i<26;i++){
    createAtZ('./');
}
```

It creates subfolder only inside A directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let fs = require("fs");
let path = require("path");

function getLetter(n) {
    return String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + n);
}

function createDirIfNotExist(dir) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }
}

function createAt(dir) {
    dir = path.join(__dirname, dir);
    createDirIfNotExist(dir);
    for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        dir = path.join(dir, getLetter(i));
        createDirIfNotExist(dir);
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    createAt(getLetter(i));
}
```

The `getLetter` function allows you to get each letter without typing out each of them. `createAt` creates the `A/B/.../Z` structure starting at a given folder. The loop at the bottom calls `createAt` on each letter `A..Z`.

In your code, `itr` is a global variable. It would be much clearer and simpler if you had one variable `0...26` for each iteration of the loop instead of a global `0...676`. You are trying to use recursion, but if you want to do that you should only call `createAtZ` once at the end of each iteration. For example:

```
function createAt(dir) {
    dir = path.join(__dirname, dir);
    createDirIfNotExist(dir);
    createAtRecursive(dir, 0);
}

function createAtRecursive(dir, itr) {
    if (itr < 26) {
        dir = path.join(dir, getLetter(itr);
        createDirIfNotExist(dir);
        createAtRecursive(dir, itr + 1);
    }
}
```

This way, it is easier to keep track of your variables since they are distinct for each call of the function.